# Visual Composer editor is behaving incorrectly on Wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

On a Wordpress site, we have a the Visual Composer by WPBakery plugin installed. For most of the pages, it is working fine, but for one page it is actually outputting the code rather than the nice WYSIWYG my client is used to seeing.

Any thoughts on what is causing this and how to remedy?

[image: Visual Composer Editor]

**EDIT**

This is what it looks like if I click the 'Backend Editor' button.

[image]

Comment: apparently since our version of Visual Composer was bundled with a theme we purchased and installed, that means we don't have access to upgrades for VC, and the plugin was stuck at v4.6.  Purchased a license directly from the plugin author, and was able to install the current v5.1.  Things have definitely improved, but I still see the shortcodes on the visual tab of the classic editor.  I'm not super familiar familiar with the plugin, so maybe that's how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you click the Backend Editor button?
Do you use different page template?

It usually happen because the plugin is crashed with another plugin. But it can be crashed with the special template for example: contact page template.

Comment: I updated the question to include an image of what it looks like with the backed editor. i read some stuff that it might be a Yoast SEO plugin issue, but I updated that completely with no luck.  i will look into the template issue.

Comment: disable all plugins one by one until you get the visual composer back.

Comment: Thanks @AdiNugroho I'll give that a shot.